# Difference between passing pointers to functions by value and by reference

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value, delete-operator

I am trying to understand the difference between passing pointers to functions using value and reference. In my case, I am 'delete []'ing the passed pointer. I am assuming that deleting the pointer is a form of modification of that pointer. So if I pass a pointer to an array (say ptr) to a function by value, I should not be allowed to 'delete[] ptr' inside of that function. When I code up both ways of doing this (passing ptr by value as well as by reference), however, the compiler lets me delete ptr inside the function in both cases.

I am confused as I thought that I wont be able to delete any pointer which is passed by value. I am appending my simple code below. There was a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8947142/passing-pointers-to-functions-by-reference-vs-by-value-and-using-delete-on-poi) on Stack Overflow, but it doesn't answer my question since the OP there wasn't interested in modifying pointers inside functions.

```
// Understanding passing by value and reference for pointers

#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int* createNew_value(int* _oarr, int &_size);
// createNew_value() appends an integer to the input integer array _oarr. The
// value of _size is incremented by one after the call to createNew_value. The
// pointer to array _oarr is passed by value.

int* createNew_reference(int* &_oarr, int &_size);
// Same functionality as createNew_value(), but here the pointer to array _oarr
// is passed by reference.

void displayIntArray(int* _iarr,int _size);
// Just diplays elements of the passed integer array.

int main()
{
    int *int_array;
    int size;

    cout << "Enter the number of elements:";
    cin >> size;

    int_array = new int [size];

    // Initialize elements of array to consecutive integers. This initialization
    // is only here to ensure that the elements of array are not undefined.
    // Other than that this initialization doesnt serve any purpose

    for (int j = 0; j <= size - 1; j++)
        int_array[j] = j;

    // Display the starting location and elements of the filled array;    
    cout << "[main()]: int_array [before createNew_value()] = " << int_array << endl;
    displayIntArray(int_array,size);

    // Display the starting location and elements of the filled array, after
    // call to createNew_value().

    int_array = createNew_value(int_array, size);

    cout << "[main()]: int_array [after createNew_value()] = " << int_array << endl;
    displayIntArray(int_array,size);

    // Display the starting location and elements of the filled array, after
    // call to createNew_reference().

    int_array = createNew_reference(int_array, size);

    cout << "[main()]: int_array [after createNew_reference()] = " << int_array << endl;
    displayIntArray(int_array,size);

    // Finally delete int_array to prevent memory leak. 
    delete [] int_array;

    return(0);
}
// %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
int* createNew_value(int* _oarr, int &_size)
// createNew_value() accomplishes the following: It creates a pointer to an
// integer array, called temp, and allocates enough memory for storing (_size +
// 1) elements. It then copies the elements of _oarr into temp, and appends one
// more integer to temp. It then deletes the original array pointer _oarr and
// returns temp. The return value of this function is a pointer to an array with
// one element larger than the input array
{
    int* temp;

    temp = new int [_size + 1];

    //copy elements of old array, _oarr, into temp

    for(int i = 0; i <= _size - 1; i++)
        temp[i] = _oarr[i];

    temp[_size] = temp[_size - 1] + 1;

    _size++;

    cout << "[createNew()]: _oarr = " << _oarr << endl;
    cout << "[createNew()]: temp = " << temp << endl;

    delete [] _oarr;

    // Since _oarr is passed by value, C++ SHOULDNT allow me to delete[] it !!

    // QUESTION: I am passing _oarr by value here. So why does C++ allow me to
    // delete [] it? Isnt deleting equivalent to modification? If yes, how can I
    // modify _oarr if I am passing it my value?

    return(temp);
}
// %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
int* createNew_reference(int* &_oarr, int &_size)
// createNew_reference() accomplishes the following: It creates a pointer to an
// integer array, called temp, and allocates enough memory for storing (_size +
// 1) elements. It then copies the elements of _oarr into temp, and appends one
// more integer to temp. It then deletes the original array pointer _oarr and
// returns temp. The return value of this function is a pointer to an array with
// one element larger than the input array
{
    int* temp;

    temp = new int [_size + 1];

    //copy elements of old array, _oarr, into temp

    for(int i = 0; i <= _size - 1; i++)
        temp[i] = _oarr[i];

    temp[_size] = temp[_size - 1] + 1;

    _size++;

    cout << "[createNew()]: _oarr = " << _oarr << endl;
    cout << "[createNew()]: temp = " << temp << endl;

    delete [] _oarr;
    return(temp);
}

//%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
void displayIntArray(int* _iarr,int _size)
{
    cout << "{ ";

    for (int n = 0; n <= _size - 2; n++)
        cout << _iarr[n] << ", ";

    cout << _iarr[_size - 1] << " }\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`operator delete` doesn't delete the pointer itself, it deletes the object to which the pointer points. So you can create as many copies of the value of the pointer as you like, as long as you remember to throw all those values away when you delete the object.

Comment: Yep that makes it clear. Thanks.  To reiterate, if there is a pointer p1 and I create its copy `p2 = p1` and `delete p2` then p1 and p2 are both dangling. Am I on the right track here?

Comment: Indeed. The alternative is to use one of the various sorts of smart pointers that handle the boring stuff for you.

Answer (score 0):

best way to think about the pointers is like a cup of water. If you pass a pointer/reference there is only 1 cup of water in existence any changes to the cup like adding food color will happen to anything using that cup. However pass by value is like creating a second cup of water that is identical, however if you add food coloring to that cup the original cup still is clear.

It's typical that when you pass by reference you want to affect the object in memory without needing to return it to the calling function. Where as a pass by value you would have do return it to the previous function and over write the previous object.

Does that help you understand it better?

Comment: Kind of. I thought there were two cups even in this case as passing pointer by "value" would create another pointer pointing to the location of the original pointer. However, that is not the case. Passing pointers by value does not seem to create its copy.